# Use of tin plating

Tags: pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

I have been researching about PCB development, and I came across the tin plating process. Consider the following scenario: I have created a PCB, covered it with solder mask, and I am now ready to solder the components on the PCB.

That means that the only copper not covered by solder mask, will now be covered by solder wire, while connecting the components.

So, my question is, why and when should the tin plating process come into play in the above-mentioned procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copper oxidizes rapidly, compromising your ability to solder it later. Tin plating (or [HASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_solder_leveling)) as part of the fabrication process greatly extends the shelf life of unassembled boards by protecting the copper.

Comment: If I, however, assemble it immediately, then there would be no point to tin-plate it, right?

Comment: What about the problem of tin whiskers?

Comment: @vu2nan: Tin whiskers is a problem associated with lead-free solders; mostly solved now. It's simply not an issue with pure tin or regular tin-lead solder.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Only time will tell!

Answer (score 5):

If you solder it immediately there is no need for any kind of coating. Normally there can be some delay between PCB manufacture and assembly so a coating of some kind is used.

Possibilities include nickel barrier + gold plating, HASL (hot air solder levelling) and OSP (organic solderability  preservative). The latter looks more-or-less like bare copper to the eye.

In a pinch you can coat the clean board with liquid **rosin** flux such as Kester 44 and it will remain solderable for some time.

Plain tin is not all that great- it will corrode. Many years ago I used electroless tin on DIY PCBs and found it corroded fairly rapidly.

Comment: Many, many years ago I bought a power supply kit with a bare copper PCB. The instructions said to use steel wool to remove the oxide, then insert the parts and solder immediately. Worked fine, but you certainly wouldn't want this extra step if you were building more than a few.

Comment: @Mattman944 Commercial copper polishes work nicely, but you have to make sure they're cleaned off thoroughly. I'd worry about steel wool slivers too (and whatever is in the soap they put on them). Ever put high current through steel wool? ;-)

Comment: "Ever put High current through steel wool ?". I did. Used for igniter on model rocket motor.